# Center text and navigation align

Tags: html, css

I have a title and a navigation under it, and I can't align them to be on the center of div...I want "Onze producten" to be a title, and then, the navigation menu to be aligned center under the title.
I can't figure it out how can I make it

This is how I want it to look...

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="section2">
            <div class="content2">
                <p><span style="font-size:30px; color:#fdd400">Onze producten</span></p>
                <ul id="nav2">
                    <li class="active">Particulier</li>
                    <li>Zakelijk</li>
                    <li>Alle producten ></li>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.section2
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
.content2
{
    height: 110px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#nav2 
{
    list-style: none outside none;
    font-size:16px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:14.5%;
    margin-top:-17px;
    color:#6e6e6e;
}
#nav2 li 
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
.clearfix 
{
    clear: both;
}
#nav2 li:hover:after, #nav2 li.active:after
{
    border: 1px solid #044584;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
}
.active
{
    color:#044584;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell if this is not what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/hgto6qhe/

Comment: I want the navigation to be aligned on center, under the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you :) http://jsfiddle.net/matjazmav/hgto6qhe/3/

```
#nav2 
{
    list-style: none outside none;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-left:14.5%;
    margin-top:-17px;
    color:#6e6e6e;

    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Also edit height to 120:

```
.content2
{
    height: 120px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I am glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block instead of floating divs

```
#nav2 
{
    list-style: none outside none;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-top:-17px;
    color:#6e6e6e;
}
#nav2 li 
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1sr5csbv/1/